# Is there a way to generate groups, rings, fields, etc.?

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, field-theory

There are ways to generate a list of numbers $a_1, a_2,...a,n$ such that no $a_i,a_j$ share any factors, mainly by letting $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-a_n+1$ with $a_0>1$, my question is: is there a way to generate rings, groups, fields, etc. that is analogous to the above method?

Comment: Generally how you would proceed is by finding isomorphic groups, rings and fields (i.e. you just copy existing ones and tweak them a little). If you are asking about construction of new structures, then it might be more problematic (might have to guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say no (even though the answer is really yes) and here's why:

The process you are describing above is an algorithm -- given a finite set of numbers define recursively the next number and then solve.

For algebraic objects, of course there are constructions that you could imagine mimic these operations but they are very different. For example, a product of two groups $G,H$ would be $G\times H$ which is a new group. But it is just all ordered pairs from the previous groups under component wise operations. This isn't as satisfying because presumably we already knew what $G$ and $H$ were.

If we asked, for finite groups $G,H$ for example, what are all groups isomorphic to $G\times H$? Then we are getting "new groups" but it's a very hard problem to solve. It is not as easy as simply multiplying elements or subtracting and such. A similar story holds for rings and for fields (but for fields, $F,K$, $F\times K$ is *not* a field defined as the product of rings).

So, before I address an analogy to the problem you've described, let's address subobjects. These are more abundant and typically have better operations. For example, there are operations of ideals: quotients, sums, products, powers, etc. But in this case, all of this is happening under the same ring $R$. So we are not producing anything "new", we are just looking at things we couldn't express or even knew existed before!

Now there are two pretty cool ways to construct new rings that I'll address via sequences. That is, given a sequence of rings $$\cdots\rightarrow R_{i-1} \rightarrow R_i \rightarrow R_{i+1} \rightarrow \cdots$$
we can construct an inverse limit, and a direct limit. (In categories the inverse limit is a limit of the inverse system, and the direct limit is just a colimit of the system; fancy names for stuff that's intuitive). Why is this intuitive? Well, the inverse limit is "where everything comes from", and the directed limit is "where everything is going".

More formally, this means there are compatible maps at each index which map from the inverse limit to this sequence, and map from this sequence to the directed limit. In general, these are pretty abstract objects. One way to look at them is to view the inverse limit as the "smallest subobject of the product $\prod_i R_i$ which satisfies the mapping condition" and the directed limit is "the quotient of $\coprod_i R_i$ by an equivalence relation if elements are mapped to each other".

This is certainly one way of getting an object which we didn't have before from a bunch of objects that we did have and is in some ways analogous to the algorithm you provided in your question. It is just, often times, harder to characterize than it would be in the case of the integers.

---

Edit: As a remark, often times we begin with objects of study in algebra (i.e. polynomials, or continuous functions) that can be described as an algebraic object. Our goal is usually to decompose this big, interesting object, into smaller ones that are easier to work with. Whenever we have constructions for new objects from old ones, it is in order to identify subobjects in the bigger object which look like those smaller ones. So we really start with a big object, try to decompose it, and then add constructions as we realize that there are a lot of objects with the same properties.

For example, if we have an algebraic object $O$ it would be nice to write $O\cong G_1\times G_2\times G_3$ where $G_i$ are simple objects. This is analogous to writing $30=2\times 3 \times 5$. But for groups, rings and fields there isn't a guaranteed way to write the object that we know of. Conversely, given these smaller objects we can make other objects but it is a hard problem to classify them. Analogously, given $2,3,5$ we can make $2\times 3 \times 5$ but we wouldn't necessarily know that this is $30$.